# Root Field of $x^4 +ax^2 + b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

This question originates from Pinter's Abstract Algebra Chapter 31 Exercise C5.

> Prove that if $p(x) = x^4 +ax^2 + b$ is irreducible in $F[x]$, then
> $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is the root field of $p(x)$ over $F$.

Let $c$ be a root of $p(x)$, so
$\displaystyle F(c)\cong \frac{F[x]}{\langle p(x)\rangle}$ where
$[F(c):F]=4$.
\begin{align*}
    p(x) &= x^4 + ax^2 +b \\
    &= \left(x^2+\frac{a}{2}\right)^2 + \left(b-\frac{a^2}{4}\right)
\end{align*}

Let $\displaystyle y=x^2+\frac{a}{2}$,
\begin{align*}
    p(y) &= y^2 + \left(b-\frac{a^2}{4}\right)
\end{align*}

Let $d_1, d_2$ be the roots of $p(y)$, so $[F(d_1):F]=2$.  As every extension of degree 2
is a root field, $d_1,d_2\in F(d_1) = F(d_2)$.
Note the values of $x$ that satisfies $\displaystyle d_1=x^2+\frac{a}{2}$ are exactly
the roots of the irreducible polynomial $\displaystyle x^2+\frac{a}{2}-d_1$ over $F(d_1)$.

Let $e_{11},e_{12}$ be the roots of $\displaystyle x^2+\frac{a}{2}-d_1$, so $[F(d_1,e_{11}):F(d_1)]=2$. This implies $e_{11},e_{12}\in F(d_1,e_{11})$ is a root field of $\displaystyle x^2+\frac{a}{2}-d_1$ over $F(d_1)$.  Similarly, let $e_{21},e_{22}$ be the roots of $\displaystyle x^2+\frac{a}{2}-d_2$, so $e_{21},e_{22}\in F(d_2,e_{21}) = F(d_2,e_{22})$.

Note

1. $F(d_1,e_{11})$ and $F(d_1,e_{21})$ are both finite extensions of $F(d_1)$;
2. $F(d_1,e_{11})$ is a root field;
3. We can construct an isomorphism $h: F(d_1,e_{11})\rightarrow F(d_1,e_{21})$ which fixes $F(d_1)$ with $h(e_{11})=e_{21}$ and $h(e_{12})=e_{22}$. This implies $F(d_1,e_{11}) = F(d_1,e_{21})$, which therefore contains all the roots of $p(x)$ over $F$.

Note $F(d_1,e_{11})$ is a minimal field extension of $F$, and $c\in F(d_1,e_{11})$.
This implies $F(d_1,e_{11})\subseteq F(c)$.  Conversely, $F(c)\subseteq F(d_1,e_{11})$.
Hence $F(c) = F(d_1,e_{11})$, which is the root field of $p(x)$ isomorphic to
$\displaystyle \frac{F[x]}{\langle p(x)\rangle}$.

Does this look reasonable?

Comment: By root field, do you mean that "all roots of $p(x)$ are contained in $F(c)$"? Is $F$ assumed finite - if not then with $F = \mathbb{Q}$ the polynomial $x^4 + 2$ provides a counterexample.

Comment: Quote from the book: If $a(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ in $F[x]$, let its roots be $c_1,\cdots, c_n$. Then $F(c_1, \cdots, c_n)$ is clearly the smallest extension of $F$ containing all the roots of $a(x). F(c_1, \cdots, c_n)$ is called the root field of $a(x)$ over $F$.

Comment: A search for "splitting field" may be more productive for you. With the stated hypotheses the result is false. When $F = \mathbb{Q}$ the polynomial $x^4 + 2$ has splitting field $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4}, i)$ which is not $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^4 + 2)$. The result is true in much greater generality when $F$ is finite.

Comment: As I understand from the book, I don't think $F$ is limited to finite field.

Comment: As I said above, this is just untrue sadly. To be very specific with my example if $\alpha = 2^{1/4}$ is a (real) 4th root of 2, then $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is contained in $\mathbb{R}$, however $(i\alpha)^4 = i^4 \alpha^4 = 2$, but $i\alpha \notin \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ since it is not real.

Comment: For the polynomial $x^4+2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, the root field is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}, i)$, since the solutions are $\pm\sqrt[4]{2}\pm i\sqrt[4]{2}$.  $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}, i):\mathbb{Q}]=4 = \displaystyle\left[\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{\langle x^4+2\rangle}:\mathbb{Q}\right]$.  Why is it a counter example?

Comment: you are correct, the root field is $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4}, i)$ however you have incorrectly said that this field has degree 4 over $\mathbb{Q}$ - in fact the degree is $8$. I'd be happy to continue this discussion in chat.